# sh dev/null Permission denied apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac-osx, shell

I am using Mac osx Mountain Lion for development.

I am trying to execute a shell command in php using the 'exec' function. At the end of my command I am putting the output to > /dev/null 2>dev/null &.

However it does not work and the error in /var/log/apache2/error_log is:

```
sh: dev/null: Permission denied
```

How can I get this to work without throwing this error?

Comment: Read closely as to what the error messages says.  It's the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you seem to have missed the leading `/`. is it possible you entered `dev/null` instead of `/dev/null`?

Comment: redirecting stdout and stderr i would do that way: > /dev/null 2>&1